# Dynamics CRM event triggers on change in entity entries?

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm

I am building an app which requires an event trigger whenever someone add, update or removes any entry from custom entities.

I could have done it using Azure Schedulars or worker roles or functions to keep querying CRM and look for changes but I was wondering if there is any such event that will trigger the hook whenever there are changes?

Regards,
Rahul

Comment: There is built in integration between the Azure service bus and the Dynamics CRM event execution pipeline. There are a couple of options including queue, synchronous one way, synchronous two way, and topics. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334766.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Your best first stop should be [Azure Logic Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-what-are-logic-apps/). This is fully managed workflow service, which has [connectors](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-connectors-list/) and [Managed APIS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/apis-list/) a lot of SaaS applications, including [Dynamics CRM Online](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/connectors-create-api-crmonline/).

**UPDATE**

And [here is a web page which fully describes all the various limits you will have when developing a logic app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-limits-and-config/). This will help you identify whether you need a single Logic App, a Parent-Child relation (or nested logic apps), or just 2 or more logic apps. All depends on your concrete case.

**UPDATE 2**

With regards to Bvrce comment - you can use the Azure Service Bus integration of CRM Online and then create a worflow (Logic App) to listen to that service bus Qeue. Ability to listen to event hub is present in [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/). But this approach will give you two separate surfaces to manage and maintain. While using the direct integration of Logic Apps will give you just a single plate to manage.

Comment: I checked Azure Logic Apps. The question is, will one logic app be sufficient for multiple entities in CRM?

Comment: @astaykov The Logic Apps CRM Connector polls CRM and pulls events out, whereas the service bus coupling is reactive in that it pushes events from CRM. OP should be able to implement the Logic Apps solution faster. I think the event-based solution would be a better option if CRM is busy and the load on the web services needs to be reduced. It would be interesting to see a performance comparison between the two. I think both solutions would be appropriate in different situations. Th right "first stop" probably is Logic Apps as you have said; it is a new option and I have not tried it out yet.